# Remove xml encoding attribute

Tags: c#, xml

I'm from c++ programming background and i have implemented a project in c++ to send and receive the data from the server using xml messages .i'm rewriting the code in c# and i'm unable to receive the data from the server as the server is unable to recognize the xml format  as it has the encoding attribute .The server is implemented in vc++ and uses utf-16 encoding for its xml messages . I just need to remove the encoding attribute in the xml message which i'm sending . as per the msdn forum http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5366y21d.aspx to remove the encoding we have to mention the encoding field as null to remove the attribute . But if i mention the second argument as null , the program doesn't seem to compile . i have mentioned the code below .Please let me know how to remove the encoding attribute from the xml message and best way to write the tcp ip client to get the data from the server .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Net.Sockets;


namespace Csharpproject.Exercises
{
    class Createxml
    {


        static void Main()
        {

            int random;
            Random data = new Random();
            random=data.Next();


            StringWriter str = new StringWriter();

            XmlTextWriter xml = new XmlTextWriter(str); //XmlTextWriter(str,null )gives error 

            xml.WriteStartDocument();



            xml.WriteStartElement("App");

            xml.WriteAttributeString("version", "1.0");



            xml.WriteStartElement("request");


            xml.WriteElementString("MessageId",random.ToString());


            xml.WriteElementString("operation","GetAgentData" );

            xml.WriteEndElement();


            xml.WriteEndElement();

            xml.WriteEndDocument();

            string result = str.ToString();



           // Console.WriteLine(result);

            Sockconnect(result);

        }

        static  public void Sockconnect(string Data)
        {
            /* creating an TCP Socket */

            string Recvdata;

           /* convert string to byte data */

            byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Data);

         /*buffer to receive the data */

            byte[] recv=new byte[4000];

        /* number of bytes sent */
            int sent = 0;

          /* number of bytes received */
            int received = 0;

            int datalen;


            datalen = data.Length;

       /* create socket */
            Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
      /* connect locally */
            try
            {
                s.Connect("127.0.0.1", 4916);
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ae)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ae.ToString());

            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString());

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Connected successfully ");

            Console.WriteLine("Sending the data ");

          /* send the data */
            do
            {

                try
                {
                    sent += s.Send(data, sent, datalen - sent, SocketFlags.None);
                }
                catch (SocketException se)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", se.ToString());
                }

            } while (sent < datalen);

            Console.WriteLine("Sent Successfully ");

          /* receive the data */

            try
            {

                received = s.Receive(recv, SocketFlags.None);

            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Received some data");

            Recvdata = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(recv);

            Console.WriteLine(Recvdata);

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a compiler error because there is no `XmlWriter` constructor that takes a `TextWriter` and an `Encoding`.  The constructor you link to takes a filename (not a `TextWriter`) and an encoding.

Even if you were to use one of the other `XmlTextWriter` constructors with the encoding to `null`, your XML document will be written out using UTF-8, when you say that your server uses UTF-16.

Normally it is best practice to avoid manipulating XML using string operations.  However, if I was in this situation, I would use string operations to chop the `encoding` attribute out.   I would be careful doing so: something like

```
result = result.Replace(" encoding=\"utf-16\"", "");
```

may have the unintended side-effect of removing this attribute from elsewhere in your XML document if it happened to be there.

Comment: good suggestion , but it didnt seem to work . i went through examples on the internet where they have performed serialization and sent  the data over the socket . do we have to do the same here .here i'm converting the string data onto byte array and sending over the socket .

Comment: @blitz: 'it didn't seem to work'?  Was there an error, and if so, what was the message?  'it didn't seem to work' isn't a lot to go on.

Comment: sorry for not updating the reply correctly . What i meant to say is that the server was still rejecting the xml which i was sending through the socket . So is this the right way to do things in c# or there are any better ways to do .

Comment: @blitz: is there any more detailed message returned by the server, or is it just a generic failure message?  I think your C# code is fine, but if your server is genuinely failing to parse an XML document if the `encoding` attribute is specified, then the problem is with the server.  Nonetheless, it might be worth double-checking that the server does use UTF-16 and that `Encoding.Default` is also UTF-16.

Comment: :Thanks for all the help .The server will send a failure xml  message if we send an incorrect xml data to it . i'll check with the colleague who has implemented the server . He has implented the server in vc++ and i remeber he had used wchart in places ,earlier i had to do the same from linux box where i had to convert my data in Utf-8 to utf-16 Little endian using iconv routine and then send the data to the server  so UTF-16 it is .